# Bind Element to different DataContext property

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

forgive this question - just learning WPF and it's making my brain hurt. Can't get my head around Bindings/DataContexts. XAML below produced via some code monkery (my knowledge of WPF not good enough atm to know what is helpful to post or not):

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"         
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:MoveResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        xmlns:paz="clr-namespace:Wpf.Controls.PanAndZoom;assembly=Wpf.Controls.PanAndZoom" 
        Title="Move and resize" Height="550" Width="750" Loaded="Window_Loaded" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" KeyUp="Window_KeyUp">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Custom Thumb Style-->
        <Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="1">
                            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"></SolidColorBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Stroke>
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow"></SolidColorBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <!-- MoveThumb Template -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MoveThumbTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type s:MoveThumb}">
            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" />
        </ControlTemplate>
        <!-- ResizeDecorator Template -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ResizeDecoratorTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Grid>    
                <!-- Abridged for stackoverflow posting -->            
                <s:ResizeThumb Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle }" Width="9" Height="9" Cursor="SizeNWSE" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <!-- Designer Item Template-->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                <s:MoveThumb Template="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}" Cursor="SizeAll" />
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" />
                <Control Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <paz:ZoomBorder x:FieldModifier="public" Name="zoomBorder" Stretch="None" ZoomSpeed="1.2" Background="SlateBlue" ClipToBounds="True" Focusable="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1">
        <Canvas x:Name="workspace" Background="#555" Width="1920" Height="1080" Margin="97,93,-1275,-654">
            <Path x:Name="YellowDiamond" Fill="Yellow" Data="M 0,5 5,0 10,5 5,10 Z" Stretch="Fill" IsHitTestVisible="True" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Height="124.75" Width="134.5" />
            <ContentControl Width="130" MinWidth="50" Height="130" MinHeight="50" Canvas.Top="150" Canvas.Left="150" Template="{StaticResource DesignerItemTemplate}">
                <Path x:Name="BlueDiamond" Fill="Blue" Data="M 0,5 5,0 10,5 5,10 Z" Stretch="Fill" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
            </ContentControl>
            <TextBox x:Name="widthTB" Height="23" Canvas.Left="131" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding BastardWidth, Mode=OneWay}" Canvas.Top="348" Width="120" />
        </Canvas>
    </paz:ZoomBorder>
</Window>
```

The key line is:

```
<s:ResizeThumb Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle }" Width="9" Height="9" Cursor="SizeNWSE" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

I'm wanting to set `Width` and `Height` to a property stored in certain class (PanAndZoomController). My understanding is that this is presently databound to ResizeThumb.vb. The relevant code behind:

```
Partial Public Class MainWindow

    Private _panZoomControl As New PanAndZoomController
    Public Property PanZoomController() As PanAndZoomController
        Get
            Return _panZoomControl
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As PanAndZoomController)
            _panZoomControl = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Me.DataContext = _panZoomControl
    End Sub

    Private Sub MousewheelMoved(sender As Object, e As MouseWheelEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseWheel
        _panZoomControl.ZoomFactor = zoomBorder.ZoomX
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class PanAndZoomController

    Private _zoomFactor As Double
    Public Property ZoomFactor() As Double
        Get
            Return _zoomFactor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            _zoomFactor = value
            _scaledWidth = 10 * _zoomFactor
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _scaledWidth As Double = 10
    Public Property ScaledWidth() As Double
        Get
            Return _scaledWidth
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            _scaledWidth = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Thus, Width and Height should be populated from `MainWindow.PanZoomController.ScaledWidth.` Could someone help out with how to achieve this? In as little XAML as possible, please!? I still need to preserve the binding of that element to `s:ResizeThumb` due to the code behind.

**EDIT: In response to ASh's suggestions.**

I've tried NotifyPropertyChanged with what I think is the right way, but still no joy :(

Simplified code scenario. Relevant code behind:

```
Public Class Workspace
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName))
    End Sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _canvasZoomFactor As Double = 1
    Public Property CanvasZoomFactor() As Double
        Get
            Return _canvasZoomFactor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            _canvasZoomFactor = value
            _handleWidth = 5 * value
            Me.NotifyPropertyChanged("HandleWidth")
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _handleWidth As Double = 5
    Public ReadOnly Property HandleWidth() As Double
        Get
            Return _handleWidth
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Name="MainWorkspace" x:Class="Workspace"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:s="clr-namespace:stigzler.utility.WPFcontrols"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:stigzler.utility.WPFcontrols"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ResizeDecoratorTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="false">
            <s:ResizeThumb Width="{Binding ElementName=Workspace, Path=HandleWidth,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           Height="{Binding ElementName=Workspace, Path=HandleWidth,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                           Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"   Cursor="SizeNWSE" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        </Grid>     
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" />
            <Control Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ContentControl Width="130" MinWidth="50" Height="130" MinHeight="50" Canvas.Top="150" Canvas.Left="150" Template="{StaticResource DesignerItemTemplate}">
        <Path x:Name="BlueDiamond" Fill="Blue" Data="M 0,5 5,0 10,5 5,10 Z" Stretch="Fill" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
    </ContentControl>

</UserControl>
```

Relevant lines:

```
            <s:ResizeThumb Width="{Binding ElementName=Workspace, Path=HandleWidth,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

            Me.NotifyPropertyChanged("HandleWidth")
```

Still getting no joy. Any other suggestions (I'm still really struggling to get my head around this binding lark).

Answer (score 1):

"My understanding is that this is presently databound to ResizeThumb.vb" - there can't be a binding to a file with code.

Each binding must have a source to get values. There are some options to provide that source:

1. specify it directly, e.g.: `"{Binding Source={StaticResource}}"`;
2. use DataContext - the default option: `"{Binding Path=SomeProperty}"` - when no source is provided, then the binding will try to find requested property in a DataContext - some data associated with the View (or with part of the View - one might want to work with different data in different parts). Usually there is one DataContext per view (`Me.DataContext = _panZoomControl`)
3. use other element as binding source (via RelativeSource or ElementName), if the element are in the same view.

s:ResizeThumb is inside MainWindow view, so RelativeSource should work:

```
<s:ResizeThumb Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"  
               Width="{Binding Path=PanZoomController.ScaledWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType = {x:Type s:MainWindow}}}" 
               Height="{Binding Path=PanZoomController.ScaledWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType = {x:Type s:MainWindow}}}"
```

hint: when binding doesn't work for some reason, check Output window in Visual Studio - there can be a message describing binding problem (type mismatch, missing property, incorrect DataContext are common reasons)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, Ash. I've still got a lot of reading and adjustment to do around all this. Your code starts well - tested via setting the default value of `ScaledWidth` and seeing it reflected in the layout. However, when I change this property, it doesn't change in the layout (it stays at the same value). Any more advice on how to make this truly dynamic?

Comment: @stigzler, read about INotifyPropertyChanged interface, implement it in PanAndZoomController class, and raise PropertyChanged event from setters (for ZoomFactor and ScaledWidth) to notify the view (binding) about change in data. I am not proficient in vb.net to write an example :\

Comment: thanks again for the reply, ash. I tired it with your updated code using `INotify` but still no joy. I've since update my original post to provide a simpler code outline and what I've tried using `Inotify` - any other suggestions - this is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ASh's answer (+1) on how to actually bind to the properties, you should also implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface in your `PanAndZoomController` class in order for the view to be refreshed whenever you set the `ZoomFactor` and `ScaledWidth` properties dynamically:

```
Public Class PanAndZoomController
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _zoomFactor As Double
    Public Property ZoomFactor() As Double
        Get
            Return _zoomFactor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            _zoomFactor = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged(NameOf(ZoomFactor))
            ScaledWidth = 10 * _zoomFactor
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _scaledWidth As Double = 10
    Public Property ScaledWidth() As Double
        Get
            Return _scaledWidth
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            _scaledWidth = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged(NameOf(ScaledWidth))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(info As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub
End Class
```